# Are functions `matplotlib.pyplot.isinteractive` and `matplotlib.is_interactive` the same?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've found two functions for detecting Matplotlib's interactive mode state:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.isinteractive
matplotlib.is_interactive
```

Documentation of the latter suggests it's only about redrawing status (while for the earlier it confirms it's about interactive mode), yet they seem to work exactly the same:

```
>>> plt.ion(); mp.is_interactive(); plt.isinteractive()
True
True
>>> plt.ioff(); mp.is_interactive(); plt.isinteractive()
False
False
```

My question: are they the same or is there any hidden internal in it that I'm missing?

Comment: The [source](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#isinteractive) is pretty useful here.

Comment: Wow. That's what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on comment by *bnaecker*:

The function `matplotlib.pyplot.isinteractive()` returns the value from `matplotlib.is_interactive()`.

The matplotlib docs show that the function `is_interactive()` in [Source code for matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib.html):

```
def is_interactive():
    """Return whether to redraw after every plotting command."""
    return rcParams['interactive']
```

is called by `isinteractive()` in [Source code for matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#isinteractive):

```
def isinteractive():
    """
    Return if pyplot is in "interactive mode" or not.

    If in interactive mode then:

      - newly created figures will be shown immediately
      - figures will automatically redraw on change
      - `.pyplot.show` will not block by default

    If not in interactive mode then:

      - newly created figures and changes to figures will
        not be reflected until explicitly asked to be
      - `.pyplot.show` will block by default

    See Also
    --------
    ion : enable interactive mode
    ioff : disable interactive mode

    show : show windows (and maybe block)
    pause : show windows, run GUI event loop, and block for a time
    """
    return matplotlib.is_interactive()
```